# ItextSharp - Can't open this File. There is a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m with the format of the File

Tags: vb.net, itext

I am trying to convert html content to pdf using itextsharp. I have both the xmlworker and itextsharp of Version 5.5.4. While trying to execute the code, a pdf file is generated in the path mentioned at C:/Test but am unable to open the file. I am using an external css file which is also given below for reference.

```
body {margin: 0;font-family: Arial;font-size: 10px;}
table {border-collapse: collapse;font-size: 13px; font-weight:bold; width:100%; border-color:black;}
.NoTableTop{border-top:none;}
tr.NoTop td{border-top:none;}
tr.NoBot td {border-bottom-color:white;}
```

```
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">")
        sb.Append("<head><title></title></head><body>")
        sb.Append("<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=""1""> ")
        sb.Append("<tr><td>")
        sb.Append("<div style=""float:left;"" width=""50%"">&nbsp;<img style=""padding-top:3px;"" src=""C:/image1.jpg"" width=70 height=75 style=""vertical-align:middle;"" /></div>")
        sb.Append("<div style=""float:right; padding:8px""><img src=""c:/images/Logo.jpg"" width=""400"" height=""70"" /></div>")
        sb.Append("</td></tr>")
        sb.Append("<tr style=""vertical-align:middle;"">")
        sb.Append("<td style=""padding:3px; vertical-align:middle;"">")
        sb.Append("<div align=""center"" width=""50%"">Company Invoice - JAN 2015")
        sb.Append("</div></td></tr><tr><td>")
        sb.Append("<div align=""center"" width=""50%"">Invoice Details</div>")
        sb.Append("</td></tr></table>")
        sb.Append("<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=""1"" class=""NoTableTop"">")
        sb.Append("<tr class=""NoTop"">")
        sb.Append("<td width=""15%""><div align=""center"">&nbsp; Name of the Company</div></td>")
        sb.Append("<td>&nbsp;Company1</td>")
        sb.Append("<td><div align=""center"">&nbsp;No.</div></td>")
        sb.Append("<td><div align=""center"">12345</div></td></tr>")
        sb.Append("<tr><td><div align=""center"">&nbsp; Department</div></td>")
        sb.Append("<td colspan=""3""><div>&nbsp;Dept 1</div></td></tr></table>")
```

I have two codes for generating the PDF

**Code 1**

```
        Dim html As New StringReader(sb.ToString)

        Using Stream As New MemoryStream
            Using doc As New iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10)
                Using writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Stream)
                    writer.CloseStream = False
                    Dim xmlworker = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance
                    doc.Open()
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, html)
                    doc.Close()
                    writer.Close()
                    Stream.Close()
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("inline;filename={0}.pdf", "filename"))
                    Response.BufferOutput = False
                    Response.BinaryWrite(Stream.ToArray())
                    Response.Flush()
                    Response.Close()
                    Response.End()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```

**Code 2**

```
        Dim Document As New iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10)
        Dim PdfWriter As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Document, New FileStream("C:/Test/Jan15.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        Dim HtmlContext As New HtmlPipelineContext(Nothing)
        HtmlContext.SetTagFactory(iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory)
        Dim CSSResolver As ICSSResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(True)
        '--- The location of the external CSS file
        Dim BCMiCss As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/style/style12.css")
        '--- Add the external CSS file        
        CSSResolver.AddCssFile(BCMiCss, True)
        Dim Pipeline As IPipeline = New CssResolverPipeline(CSSResolver, New HtmlPipeline(HtmlContext, New PdfWriterPipeline(Document, PdfWriter)))
        Dim Worker As XMLWorker = New XMLWorker(Pipeline, True)
        Dim Parser As XMLParser = New XMLParser(True, Worker)
        Parser.Parse(New StringReader(sb.ToString))
        Parser.Flush()
```

Code 2 does not make use of the external file. I tried adding a style tag in the string builder "sb". Nothing worked.

```
        sb.Append("<style type=""text/css"">")
        sb.Append("body {margin: 0;font-family: Arial;font-size: 10px;}")
        sb.Append("table {border-collapse: collapse;font-size: 13px; font-weight:bold; width:100%; border-color:black;}")
        sb.Append(".NoTableTop{border-top:none;}")
        sb.Append("tr.NoTop td{border-top:none;}")
        sb.Append("tr.NoBot td {border-bottom-color:white;}")
        sb.Append("</style>")
```

I am stuck with this report.

Comment: You don't close the `Document` in code 2.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanks for your response. Since I haven't opened the document in Code 2, I did not close it. Is anything wrong with the code? I am unable to identify where am going wrong. How do we make itexsharp to understand css (internal or external). I can see the css support tags made in the site. [link](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/index.html). Any help pls. I would like to have the report downloaded (as coded in Code 1)

Comment: Have you checked that the HTML is valid? You could save `sb.ToString()` to a file and use the [W3 HTMLmarkup validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).